# excel file reading error in C#

Tags: iis-7, c#-4.0

i am tring to read excel file but the iis7 is giving this error:

"Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file 'D:\Demosites\Domaininterface\Keywordsfolder\keywords2172011 23841 PM.xlsx'. There are several possible reasons: • The file name or path does not exist. • The file is being used by another program. • The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook."

someone know about this?

Comment: There are several possible reasons: • The file name or path does not exist. • The file is being used by another program. • The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

Comment: but this same code is working in ii6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the path is explicit, it *sounds* like a permissions issue - simply: the account that the application / app-pool is running as (in IIS) doesn't have access to that folder.

However, unless it has changed recently, you should note that Excel is not supported for use on a server - it is desktop software, and you may run into a *multitude* of issues using it on a server. And I have *no idea* whether this would be a licensed scenario ;p